# Powershell not running color changes on start up

Tags: powershell

I've had this working consistently but I've just updated windows and now my powershell profile isn't updating colors correctly.

Profile code that was working previously:

```
Set-PSReadLineOption -Colors @{
"ContinuationPrompt" =     [ConsoleColor]:: DarkGray
"Emphasis" =     [ConsoleColor]:: DarkGray    
"Error" =     [ConsoleColor]:: DarkGray
"Selection" =     [ConsoleColor]:: DarkGray
"Default" =     [ConsoleColor]:: DarkGray
"Comment" =     [ConsoleColor]:: DarkGray
"Keyword" =     [ConsoleColor]:: DarkGray
"String" =     [ConsoleColor]:: DarkGray
"Operator" =     [ConsoleColor]:: DarkGray
"Variable" =     [ConsoleColor]:: DarkGray
"Command" =     [ConsoleColor]:: DarkGray
"Parameter" =     [ConsoleColor]:: DarkGray
"Type" =     [ConsoleColor]:: DarkGray
"Number" =     [ConsoleColor]:: DarkGray
"Member" =     [ConsoleColor]:: DarkGray
}
```

When I add echo to the top it prints correctly when powershell is opened but the colors dont change.

```
echo "hello"
Set-PSReadLineOption -Colors @{
"ContinuationPrompt" =     [ConsoleColor]:: DarkGray
"Emphasis" =     [ConsoleColor]:: DarkGray    
"Error" =     [ConsoleColor]:: DarkGray
"Selection" =     [ConsoleColor]:: DarkGray
"Default" =     [ConsoleColor]:: DarkGray
"Comment" =     [ConsoleColor]:: DarkGray
"Keyword" =     [ConsoleColor]:: DarkGray
"String" =     [ConsoleColor]:: DarkGray
"Operator" =     [ConsoleColor]:: DarkGray
"Variable" =     [ConsoleColor]:: DarkGray
"Command" =     [ConsoleColor]:: DarkGray
"Parameter" =     [ConsoleColor]:: DarkGray
"Type" =     [ConsoleColor]:: DarkGray
"Number" =     [ConsoleColor]:: DarkGray
"Member" =     [ConsoleColor]:: DarkGray
}
```

Comment: What version OS and Powershell?  Btw you can shorten them like this:  `Member = 'DarkGray'`

Comment: @js2010 Windows 10 Version 1909. Tried with Powershell Version 5.1.18362 and Powershell 6.2.3

Comment: Hmm I'm in that OS now and it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it works for me, and you can just say 'DarkGray' for the color.  The only caveat is you can't use "`e" in powershell 5.  Note that Windows Terminal redefines colors in its schemes, like any console program.

In terms of escape sequences, DarkGray becomes "bright black" or "esc[90m" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors_  The console colors and the ansi colors have some different adjectives.

Some of the commonly used codes in psreadline.  Some of these become invisible in windows terminal's solarized schemes, because bright white or bright black are set an equal color to the background.

```
Command            "$([char]0x1b)[31m" red # 93 bright yellow
Comment            "$([char]0x1b)[32m" green
ContinuationPrompt "$([char]0x1b)[37m" white # 33 yellow
DefaultToken       "$([char]0x1b)[37m" white
Emphasis           "$([char]0x1b)[96m" bright cyan
Error              "$([char]0x1b)[91m" bright red
Keyword            "$([char]0x1b)[92m" bright green
Member             "$([char]0x1b)[97m" bright white
Number             "$([char]0x1b)[97m" bright white
Operator           "$([char]0x1b)[90m" bright black
Parameter          "$([char]0x1b)[90m" bright black
Selection          "$([char]0x1b)[30;47m" black on white # 35;43 magenta;yellow
String             "$([char]0x1b)[36m" cyan
Type               "$([char]0x1b)[37m" white
Variable           "$([char]0x1b)[92m" bright green
```